# Best way to check if a large HashMap contains a key?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, hashmap

as i first found out about hashmaps i was amazed by it and i started working with, i have been using .contains to check if a hashmap contains a given key before i access it, but now i wonder if there might be a better (more efficient and fast way) to determinate if it contains a key.

im quite not sure how .contains works but simply using .get and checking if the returned value/object is not null sounds like a better/faster way (might be totally wrong about it but now i use large hashmaps and it might be good to use the best way). have been reading that .getOrDefault might be also a way, could someone help me choosing the right way? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: I would suggest you examine the current HashMap implementation in OpenJDK as well as the Map interface so you understand it

Comment: "checking if the returned value/object is not null sounds like a better/faster way" depends if you ever expect `null` to be a key: `HashMap` does support that.

Comment: `containsKey`, `get`, and `getOrDefault` all do the same lookup.  The one thing you want to avoid is doing more than one lookup for the same key, so `get` is usually the best choice.  Unless, as Andy Turner pointed out, your HashMap actually has a null key in it.